# populate_sdk command can't satisfy a nativesdk package I know exists

Tags: yocto

I have a recipe which produces -native and nativesdk- packages, but when I try to populate the SDK I get the following error message:

```
~/myproj/build$ bitbake -c populate_sdk core-image-minimal
... lots of error messages ...
Collected errors:
 * opkg_prepare_url_for_install: Couldn't find anything to satisfy 'nativesdk-myapp'.
```

However, I have no trouble building that package:

```
~/myproj/build$ bitbake myapp myapp-native nativesdk-myapp
```

The recipe in question uses `BBCLASSEXTEND` to add the extra packages.  It is very simple: just a standard cmake recipe that changes a couple of config parameters to omit unit tests from the native and nativesdk builds:

```
inherit cmake

SUMMARY = "My Application"
SRC_URI = "git://git@bitbucket.mydomain.com/project/myapp"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git/"

DEPENDS += "gnutls protobuf protobuf-native dlt-daemon"
DEPENDS_append_class-target = " gtest"

EXTRA_OECMAKE_append_class-native = " -DAPP_FEATURE_TEST=Off"
EXTRA_OECMAKE_append_class-nativesdk = " -DAPP_FEATURE_TEST=Off"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

Finally, I have the following lines in my distro file:

```
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append += " myapp-dev nativesdk-myapp"
```

I can build the nativesdk-myapp package just fine, but for some reason the populate_sdk target can't find it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in the distro file.  It should have read:

```
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append += " myapp-dev"

TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK_append += " nativesdk-myapp"
```

`TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK` is the SDK packages that go into the target sysroot, which in this case is ARM on a Jacinto SoC.

`TOOLCHAIN_HOST_TASK` is the SDK packages that go into the host sysroot, which is x86_64.

Yocto was very sensibly complaining that it didn't have a nativesdk-myapp package for ARM/Jacinto.